# Broadcast receiver is not working on Ice cream sandwitch 4.0.3

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-reboot

I want to start service on reboot of the device.

First I used broadcast receiver.It worked on my android phone having version 7. But I want to implement it on Xixun controller which is android based having version 4.0.3

Broadcast receiver did not work. I have gone through reading that, for API levels below 26, one should use WakefulBroadcastReceiver. When I did that, it worked on my phone but not on Xixun controller.

The process to reboot Xixun controller is just to power on and power off using supply.I have also used power intent of broadcast receiver. But it didn't work because device is batteryless.

What would be reason behind my service is not working?

[[manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y9ds.png) [receiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF6S9.png)]

Following is service code

```
package com.example.serviceexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyService extends Service {


@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast myToast =Toast.makeText(this,"service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    myToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
    myToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


    myToast.show();
    return Service.START_STICKY;


}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

When I used broadcast receiver, codes are same except basic syntax.

Comment: Please find links attached(snippets of my code)

Comment: Please provide the snippets as text instead of images. That improves findability (e.g. when others google the same problem) and makes it easier to test whether answers given here work

Comment: Ice Cream Sandwich is no longer supported by Google.

Comment: Okay I will provide snippets

Comment: @Fantômas I am not getting. I have controller of version ice cream sandwitch